# Working with Checkboxes in Loadrunner (Web HTTP/HTML)?

Tags: checkbox, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to record a simple Web Application which as activity of checking checkboxes as below and clicking on Submit button:

[image]

After recording the script is generated a post request as below:

```
web_submit_data("NonInvObjectSubmit", 
    "Action=URL", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=URL", 
    "Snapshot=t23.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=PageStart", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=[4].bCheckBox", "Value=true", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=[4].Id", "Value=11701", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=[4].bCheckBox", "Value=false", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

Observed the Value = 11701 is incrementing for each time the checkbox is used.
Replaying the same with different Index number, doesn't actually checks the checkbox.(tried providing empty Value, Random Value but nothing worked.)

Please Help. Thank you

Comment: Correlated value?

Comment: Cant find any correlation here @JamesPulley

Comment: If your name[4].ID is changing, you have two options (1) Client Generators or (2) Server Generated.  Modify your code appropriately to handle either condition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do a manual correlation. Search the Server Response and correlate the checkbox value.